# What can I safely remove from Ubuntu and still have a decent graphic interface?

Tags: command-line, apt, gnome, python, zeitgeist

I have come to like Linux, Unix, and the GUI's but sometimes I remove too many things and lose the ability to boot back into the same interface I was using before I rebooted. most of the time I have to reinstall the OS

if I'm not programming any of the apps , and I'm not compiling any software, and I'm not using a CLI to access anything except my own computer and my own OS's, and I'm not consulting zeitgeist, and i'm not looking to spy on other people, and I'm not wanting to be spied on, and ... etc.. what can I delete?

I take off Python, but it comes back.. isn't Python a programming console?

basically I just want to be able to acess the net with firefox and use my computer as a home sound system.. I don't do much else. (except learn as mucfh as I can about computers but lately it's networking )

I use APT to remove most of the stuff, but I have found the "ubuntu-software-center" is likely to tell me if something is "necessary" but I've used that also and f--d up the system..

Answer (score 0):

Been there, did that, got the t-shirt, not doing it again! ;)

What you're *trying* to do is: "I just want Windows, not this stupid System32 stuff that is eating up all my hard disk!  Let's delete it!" ;)

I did the same thing you did and had to install from scratch as I deleted too much, and now I'm much more careful as to what to delete...

E.g. Python: Python is an interpreted programming language, so to run any Python programs, you need the interpreter... *You* personally do not need to program Python, but maybe some of the programs you use are written in Python!  :)
Compiler: you don't need to compile stuff, but Ubuntu updates do, or some driver update does!

Ubuntu come with much less cr*pware then Windows: if it's there and you don't know what it is, you probably need it...

Safe to remove: applications you're never going to need *and that take up a lot of disk space*. E.G. on a home sound system, it's safe to remove LibreOffice, Thunderbird, games, ...
**But** stuff like Bluetooth, Printers, Python, compiler, ... I wouldn't remove, because Ubuntu *expects* them to do its updates...

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do to ensure a working, clutter-free operating system, is to assemble it yourself. Start from an ubuntu minimal installation:

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso

If you install it, you just get the command line interface. From there, you can add packages such as a GUI, firefox,...

Then you can run the command to install Ubuntu desktop without any extra packages, just the hard dependencies

```
$ sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

source: 
http://ask.xmodulo.com/install-minimal-ubuntu-desktop.html